# jquery mobile responsive list design

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I'm creating a small webapp using jquery mobile 1.4.0 and I'm stuck with creating a responsive list. I have the following code (I've removed the PHP as its not relevant to this!)

```
    <div class='bespoke-bp'>
        <ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-divider-theme='a'>
            <li data-role='list-divider'>
                <div class='container_12'>
                    <div class='grid_15'>
                        <div class='ui-grid-b'>
                            <div class='ui-block-a'><div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px'>Type</div></div>
                            <div class='ui-block-b'><div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px'>Number</div></div>
                            <div class='ui-block-c'><div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px'>Primary</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>       
            <li>
                <div class='container_12'>
                    <div class='grid_15'>
                        <a href='#phoneOrEmail' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop' >
                            <div class='ui-grid-b'>
                                <div class='ui-block-a'><div id='contactDesc' class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px; background-color:transparent; border: none; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;'>" . $row['description'] . "</div></div>
                                <div class='ui-block-b'><div id='contactNo' class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px; background-color:transparent; border: none; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;'>" . $row['number'] . "</div></div>
                                <div class='ui-block-c'><div id='contactPri' class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px; background-color:transparent; border: none; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;'>" . $row['thePriNo'] . "</div></div>
                            </div>  
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class='grid_120'>
                        <a href='#editContact' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop' style='padding:0px; margin:0px; border:0px; float: right;' class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-edit ui-btn-icon-notext'>Edit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>                   
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- BESPOKE-BP end -->
```

and I have this very basic responsive css:

```
/* stack all grids below 40em (640px) */
@media all and (max-width: 35em) {
.bespoke-bp .ui-block-a,
.bespoke-bp .ui-block-b,
.bespoke-bp .ui-block-c,
.bespoke-bp .ui-block-d,
.bespoke-bp .ui-block-e {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
```

}

```
/*  Position the title next to the rank, pad to the left */
.bespoke-bp .list-divider .ui-block-a,
.bespoke-bp .list-divider .ui-block-b,
.bespoke-bp .list-divider .ui-block-c,
.bespoke-bp .list-divider .ui-block-d,
.bespoke-bp .list-divider .ui-block-e  {
    margin-top: -2.1em;
    padding-left: 2.2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

I would like to make this more "fancy" such as instead of the headers all just stacking on top of each other that they get put on each row such as:

**Type**

thetype

**number**

thenumber

**primary**

theprimary

for each row.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction with this as I don't really know where to start!

Thanks

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/N2qpD/?  You could also look at the reflow table: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/table-reflow/

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! Thats great but when you have more than one row it still shows the headers on each row, I want this to only happen when the list is being responsive. Do you know a way round this? http://jsfiddle.net/N2qpD/1/

Comment: yes, see my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your column titles in both the one list divider for wide screens and within each LI for narrow screens. Then in the CSS show/hide the appropriate titles with your media query:

```
<div class='bespoke-bp'>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="edit" data-inset='true'>
        <li data-role='list-divider' class="titleRowDivider">
            <div class='ui-grid-b'>
                <div class='ui-block-a'><div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px'>Type</div></div>
                <div class='ui-block-b'><div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px'>Type</div></div>
                <div class='ui-block-c'><div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px'>Type</div></div>                        
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
             <a href='#phoneOrEmail' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop'>
                <div class='ui-grid-b'>
                    <div class='ui-block-a'>
                        <div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a titleRow' style='height:15px'>Type</div>
                        <div id='contactDesc' class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px; background-color:transparent; border: none; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;'>" . $row['description'] . "</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='ui-block-b'>
                        <div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a titleRow' style='height:15px'>Number</div>
                        <div id='contactNo' class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px; background-color:transparent; border: none; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;'>" . $row['number'] . "</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='ui-block-c'>
                        <div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a titleRow' style='height:15px'>Primary</div>
                        <div id='contactPri' class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px; background-color:transparent; border: none; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;'>" . $row['thePriNo'] . "</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href='#editContact' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop'>Purchase album</a>                   
        </li>                
       <li>
             <a href='#phoneOrEmail' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop'>
                <div class='ui-grid-b'>
                    <div class='ui-block-a'>
                        <div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a titleRow' style='height:15px'>Type</div>
                        <div id='contactDesc' class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px; background-color:transparent; border: none; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;'>" . $row['description'] . "</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='ui-block-b'>
                        <div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a titleRow' style='height:15px'>Number</div>
                        <div id='contactNo' class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px; background-color:transparent; border: none; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;'>" . $row['number'] . "</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='ui-block-c'>
                        <div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a titleRow' style='height:15px'>Primary</div>
                        <div id='contactPri' class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height:15px; background-color:transparent; border: none; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;'>" . $row['thePriNo'] . "</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href='#editContact' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop'>Purchase album</a>                   
        </li>                  
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the CSS, the divider is shown and the repeated titles are hidden until screen size is less than 35em at which time this state is reversed:

```
.bespoke-bp .titleRow {
    display: none;
}
.bespoke-bp .titleRowDivider{
    display: block;
}
/* stack all grids below 40em (640px) */
@media all and (max-width: 35em) {
    .bespoke-bp .ui-block-a,
    .bespoke-bp .ui-block-b,
    .bespoke-bp .ui-block-c,
    .bespoke-bp .ui-block-d,
    .bespoke-bp .ui-block-e {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
    .bespoke-bp .titleRow {
        display: block;
    }    
    .bespoke-bp .titleRowDivider{
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/N2qpD/4/)**